# How to add a new category to Alfresco (webscript or webservice)?

Tags: web-services, alfresco

This is a long shot, but I'm kind of stuck here.
I need to be able to add a new category to Alfresco (programatically).

I suppose I should use `cm:categoryRoot/cm:generalclassifiable/` as parent, but I don't know how to add a new node as a category.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [official documentation](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Classification_And_Categories):

`Nodes can be created [...] of type cm:category and child association type cm:subcategories`

Normal `cm:category` nodes can be created under the `/cm:category_root/cm:generalclassifiable/**` tree using the `cm:subcategories` association type to create new categories under the `cm:generalclassfiable` classification. As such, any node creation service will be available to create new categories.

Comment: I managed to do it this way. But it only works at first glance, because after I add it, I am unable to edit or delete it. And there's a missing namespace in its path. Do you have more knowledge of Alfresco regarding this situation?